# vertical-align:top not working in td with multiple elements

Tags: html, css

I have this html ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wf1fvgpa/1/)):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" style="vertical-align:top"> <span class="" title="">Add new Comment:</span>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1" style="height:80px;vertical-align:top;">
                 text
                <textarea id="" class="" style="height:52px;vetical-align:top;"></textarea>
                 Person:
                <input id="" class="" type="text" value="" style="vetical-align:top;"/>&nbsp;
                <button class="" style="width:90px;vetical-align:top;" onclick="">Insert</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that i cant display the contents of second `td` vertically aligned top.

I saw also other answers that use the property `display: table-cell;` but doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: do you mind to use divs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo is `vertical-align` not `vetical-align:top`(also please avoid using inline styles):

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1" style="vertical-align:top"> <span class="" title="">Add new Comment:</span>
    </td>
    <td colspan="1" style="height:80px;vertical-align:top;">
      text
      <textarea id="" class="" style="height:52px;vertical-align:top;"></textarea>
      Person:
      <input id="" class="" type="text" value="" style="vertical-align:top;" />&nbsp;
      <button class="" style="width:90px;vertical-align:top;" onclick="">Insert</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" style="vertical-align: top"><span class="" title="">Add new Comment:</span>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1" style="height: 80px; vertical-align: top;">
            <div>text</div>
            <div>
                <textarea id="" class="" style="height: 52px; vetical-align: top;"></textarea></div>
            <div>Person:</div>
            <div>
                <input id="Text1" class="" type="text" value="" style="vetical-align: top;" /></div>
            <div>
                <button class="" style="width: 90px; vetical-align: top;" onclick="">Insert</button></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

used html divs around contents,have a look at [updated link](http://jsfiddle.net/wf1fvgpa/3/) please,hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td colspan="1" valign="top"> <span class="" title="">Add new Comment:</span>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1" valign="top">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" border="0">
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td>Text:</td>
                        <td><textarea id="" class="" style="height:52px;vetical-align:top;"></textarea></td>
                        <td>Person:</td>
                        <td><input id="" class="" type="text" value="" style="vetical-align:top;"/></td>
                        <td><button class="" style="width:90px;vetical-align:top;" onclick="">Insert</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>                
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```